# Why is my JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize() is not working?

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I get this JSON from Box API call:

```
   {"total_count":4,
    "entries":[
        {"type":"folder","id":"3102883693","sequence_id":"0","etag":"0","name":"Deployments"},            
        {"type":"folder","id":"3460455852","sequence_id":"0","etag":"0","name":"MARKETING"},
        {"type":"folder","id":"2535410485","sequence_id":"1","etag":"1","name":"Plans"},
        {"type":"folder","id":"3132381455","sequence_id":"0","etag":"0","name":"Projects"}, 
        ],
    "offset":0,
    "limit":100,
    "order":[
        {"by":"type","direction":"ASC"},
        {"by":"name","direction":"ASC"}
        ]
    }
```

I tried this to get it into class but I cant get my list:

```
var folders = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<FolderItems>>(response.Content);
```

Here are my classes:

```
   public class FolderItems
   {
       public int total_count { get; set; }
       public List<Entry> entries { get; set; }
       public int offset { get; set; }
       public int limit { get; set; }
       public List<Order> order { get; set; }
   }
    public class Entry
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int sequence_id { get; set; }
        public string etag { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

public class Order
{
    public string by { get; set; }
    public string direction { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: My folders list is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your JSON, you have a single outer object, not a list.

```
var folder = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FolderItems>(response.Content);
```

You should be deserializing into a single `FolderItems` object with a list of entries on that object.